# In which language did exceptions first appear?

Tags: programming-languages, history, exception

I first came across exceptions with ADA 83. As far as I know, the designers of ADA invented the concept of exceptions. Is this true, or did any programming language that came before use exceptions too?

Comment: I like how this question is almost word for word from a question you posted less than a minute earlier regarding exceptions.

Comment: In which language did semicolons first appear?

Comment: That'll be because I cut and pasted the other question, then edited it to this one, rather than retype it. I'm at a loss to understand why you seem to have a problem with that.

Comment: To preempt another question about semicolons, I'll just answer it here: semicolons as statement separators first appeared in Algol-60.

Comment: @David, There is a certain type of user who will ask multiple questions that are exactly the same in order to gain upvote points. They just change a few words here and there. This behaviour is not really accepted on SO. Which is exactly what you did, rather than retype two lines of text.

Comment: @Pavel maybe it would be nice to have this question and answer properly entered into SO, for future reference :-)

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for the explanation. I have plenty of rep thanks and don't really have any need of more, so you regrettably jumped to a false conclusion about my two questions. No harm done though.

Comment: I have merged the question. Kindly ask once - and edit the existing question if necessary.

Comment: @David, If I was jumping to conclusions I would have downvoted and flagged the question. I just found it funny, since it is a valid question, and your profile doesn't look that of someone who question spams.

Comment: What do you mean you merged the question? I asked TWO different questions! Kindly unmerge them now please and try reading the questions properly before interfering next time.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Way to merge not-actually-related questions and get me downvoted because an answer that was correct is now attached to a question it's not correct for.

Comment: @Brandon. looks like Marc Gravell did jump to conclusions though. Next time I'll know to phrase the questions differently (and maybe ask them hours apart) to prevent such a mess happening again.

I thought they'd be such simple and uncontroversial questions too. Oh dear :(

Comment: If I've misread them, then my apologies. But to casual inspection the two questions were pretty much identical. I suspect (reading the above) that there might have been a single word difference between them (exceptions vs generics?) - so you might understand my missing *one word*. Again, if I got it wrong, then sorry. There is no un-merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [c2.com's Ground Breaking Languages page](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?GroundBreakingLanguages) it was PL/I.

Comment: There was a lot of good stuff in that language.  Pity about how it all worked together.

Comment: Note: this was my answer to the question about what language *exception handling* first appeared in, which was merged with this question, IMO inappropriately.

Comment: I've changed the question to the one you answered chaos. I tried to just delete it and start again, but even as the question asker, I'm only allowed to vote to delete my own question. This place has changed a lot since I was last here.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: this answer was to a related question ("In which language did generics first appear?") which unfortunately got merged with this one by an over-enthusiastic admin.

It depends on how you define generics. Parametric polymorphism - which allows you to define functions and types that are not tied to particular argument / field types - was there in [ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_programming_language) already - and that's 1973. There is a Standard ML sample from Wikipedia:

```
fun reverse [] = []
  | reverse (x::xs) = (reverse xs) @ [x]
```

Note that this function is statically typed, but polymorphic ("generic") on any type of list.

While this example is SML (which is a later thing), so far as I know, the concept was present in earliest ML versions as well.

Comment: All folk, please note: this answer was to a related question (in which language did generics first appear) which unfortunately got merged with this one by an over-enthusiastic admin. It's not Pavel's fault it's not an answer to this question, so please do not down-vote him for it.

Answer (score -1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming):

> Generic programming facilities first
>   appeared in the 1970s in languages
>   like CLU and Ada, and were
>   subsequently adopted by many
>   object-based and object-oriented
>   languages, including BETA, C++, D,
>   Eiffel, Java, and DEC's now defunct
>   Trellis-Owl language. Implementations
>   of generics in languages such as Java
>   and C# are formally based on the
>   notion of parametricity, due to John
>   C. Reynolds.

Comment: If you're going to copy and paste from Wikipedia, at least provide the source link.

Comment: If you're going to straight copy from the Wiki page, at least cite it.

Comment: I'm confused, even before the edit he put "From wikipedia", what's the problem?

Comment: No, he didn't. He edited it after the fact, it just doesn't show the revision. Either way he did add it very quickly after the fact, so there is no problem.

Comment: @John Rasch: He had a stealth edit before the first five minutes where he added the "From Wikipedia".