# In which programming language did semicolon first appear as a separator?

Tags: history

In similar manner to this question about [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308434/in-which-language-did-generics-first-appear): In which programming language did the semicolon make its first appearance, and how did it spread to C?

Comment: I would say English, but I'm not a linguist.

Comment: @EBGReen I meant programming language, of course

Comment: Actually, according to wikipedia, the first use of the semicolon was by an italian publisher, so not English

Comment: @1800 INFORMATION - Glad to know I'm not the only one who looked that up.

Comment: > *As I said, no liguist here.* — you don’t say! 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely ALGOL.

---

Hmm, somebody changed the question. That's not quite cricket.

---

As for how it spread, well semicolons spread Algol 60 -> Simula -> C.  K+R said that Pascal didnt influence them, IIRC, though some disputed this claim.

---

Statement *terminators* (other than new-line) spread from COBOL -> Jovial -> C.  Though each had a different character as the teminator.

Comment: FORTRAN used column 72 of a punch card as a terminator, unless there was a continuation character in column 6 of the next card.  (Don't ask how I know.)  Lisp, the other survivor of the really early languages, just had statements delimited by parentheses.

Comment: No, you mean that F77 used a *continuation* character in column72.  There was no termination character in F77 (unless you count new-lines which they didnt then).

Comment: I dimly remember the amazing new concept that the thing between lines of code could be considered a character, even though, in ASCII, that's exactly what it was.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a separator in C - it's a terminator.

However, I believe [ALGOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL) may have been the first to use the semicolon in this sort of way.

Comment: separator as in "statements separator" ?

Comment: Careful.  I think in Algol the ; have been a separator (as it is in Pascal).  Not a terminator (as it is in C and Ada).

Comment: As a totally unrelated aside, OCaml's ";" is really an operator, not a terminator. It has the type unit -> 'a -> 'a, where the operator accepts two inputs and returns the second. There's a little blurb on this page (http://www.ocaml-tutorial.org/the_structure_of_ocaml_programs) which describes the ";" operator in detail.

Comment: @S.Lott: Made the answer more ambiguous :)

Comment: its called a terminator in C, but it acts like a separator

Comment: @RBarryYoung:  No, it's a statement terminator in C.  The way to tell is to look at the last statement in a block:  does it need a ; or not?  If so, it's a terminator, otherwise it's a separator.  Terminators are generally easier on the programmer than separators.

Comment: No, the way to tell a terminator is: s it required to terminate every statment, as it was in COBOL an Jovial?  It does not work that way in C. The most that can be sais in C is that ";" is more or a terminator there, than it was in Algol, Simula or Pascal.  But it's still not a true terminator.

Comment: And actually, most from that time and up through the mid to late 80's felt that C's inconsistent terminator/separator aproach was hardest of all on programmers.  (after that everyone coming out of college had been "baby ducklinged" on C and nolonger seemed capable of objective thought on the matter).  C's approach to semicolons and statement termination is really onlu an advantage for the parser/complier writers and is in fact merely a burden for the programmer.  Especially since it is entirely possbile to have languages with NO statement terminators needed.

Comment: **@R Barry Young:** 'k, the history lesson is great, but would have been a lot more relevant if you'd taken time to explain why you consider it to act as a separator first.

Answer (score 0):

Pascal had semicolons as terminators before C did; not sure if it was the first language to have them, though.

Comment: pascal as them as separators - terminators are similar but they are different.

Answer (score 0):

ALGOL is my guess too.

The significance is that it freed the user from punch-card-style fixed format.

If you have to use Fortran 77, you know what that means.

Comment: Though that was something of an irrelevant freedom in 1960.

Comment: And, IIRC, it was valid in FORTRAN-77 to use it in non-Zoned format.

Comment: @RBarry: don't you still have the line-length restriction and continuation characters? We hit that all the time.

Comment: ... not to mention only 1 statement on a line.

Comment: Mike Dunlavey:  1 statement per line, yes.  The rest, I am not sure, it's hard to sort out all of the different versions and the propietary enhancements from the standard features. (it *was* 25-35 years ago :- ).

Comment: IMHO, the more likely reason that Algol pioneered the non-line-break style of statement separation/termination ha to do with it's most common storage, presentation and execution medium: Academic Journals.  Being able to reformat the line-breaks would have been a real boon for the type-setters.  (COBOL and FORTRAN's default medium on the other-hand was punched-cards, which explains why they would favor not only line-break sensitivity, but vel "zone" (column number) sensitivity.

Comment: @RBarry: That's an interesting insight. I also wonder if it had to do with the use of paper tape by DEC. I can't remember what the Burroughs machines used for media, but I don't think it was punch cards.

Comment: ... I also just wiki'd Burroughs, then ALGOL-58, then Backus-Naur-Form, then Compound (begin-end) Statements. I didn't find a specific reference to semicolons, but it had to be in there.

Comment: I actually worked for DEC for 10 years, but they were late to most of this (DEC was a player c.73 to 90, most of this, except F77 was done prior to 72). DEC's paper-tape as descendend from the teletype ASR/KSR-33 paper-tape readers (attached to the teletypes, IIRC).  But paper-tape was never a primary medium for any langage, it was always a backup, archival or distribution medium, not the preferred one for developers or execution.  I geuss it was really an early substitute for MagTape in many ways.

Comment: I don't think that Algol-58 had semicolons.  Before my time actually, but everything I've read implies it was introduced in Algol-60.

Comment: I guess that's the mystery - did ALGOL-58 have them? BTW I worked at Teletype in the early 60's while in college, on those 33s, & I barely remember running a PDP-8 from one of those. They were pretty clever little beasts.